# Can I download Ubuntu with my Mac and transfer it via USB?

Tags: dell, mac, system, transfer

I have a dell optiflex 755 and i have fitted a new hard drive and power supply.

There is no operating system, so I am trying to install ubuntu. I need to download it on a mac and then transfer it.

Will this work?

Comment: Yes, it will work. How much ram do you have?

Comment: not sure waht ram is.. im so lost with this.. i have been to computer store twice, and online chat with tech and cant get this to work.. how do i know how much ram i have?

Comment: you said you had fitted a new hard drive, but you don't know what ram is. don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the file [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.1/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso), and then follow these instructions:

The easiest way to burn an ISO, the file you need to install Ubuntu from a DVD, is by using Disk Utility.

1. Launch 'Disk Utility' (Applications → Utilities → Disk Utility).
2. Insert your blank DVD.
3. Drag and drop your .iso file to the left pane in Disk Utility. Now both the blank disc and the .iso should be listed.
4. Select the .iso file, and click on the 'Burn' button in the toolbar.

   [image]
5. Ensure that the 'Verify burned data' checkbox is ticked (you may need to click on the disclosure triangle to see the checkbox).

   [image]
6. Click 'Burn'. The data will be burned and verified.

Taken from [ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx)

Comment: this didn't work.. saying cd/dvd not compatible.. i don't think its downloading iso correctly

Comment: I think you need to get a new dvd.